# OpenCV fill in the blank

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an original RGB image contains two colors: gray and blue, which intersect with each other. The image is read to BGR in OpenCV. Is there a way extract the gray portion and fill in the "blue" (now orange) portion where they intersect?

[Original image in BGR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElsZ2.png)

I am able to separate the two colors out using cv2.inRange(), filtering specific colors. Then, I stuck.
My code snippet and results are as below:

```
lower_gray = np.array([90, 90, 90])
upper_gray = np.array([95, 95, 95]) #BGR=(95,95,95)
data = cv.inRange(img, lower_gray, upper_gray)
cv.imshow("data", data)

# Convert to hsv to filter orange line
lower = np.array([10, 10, 200]) #BGR=(15,49,237)
upper = np.array([100, 255, 255]) #BGR=(16,144,210)

hsv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv_mask = cv.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
cv.imshow("hsv", hsv)
cv.imshow("hsv_mask", hsv_mask)

cv.waitKey(0)
```

[My current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chYYg.png)

I would like to get to this:
[Ideal results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H55mh.png)

The gray portion doesn't have a fixed shape. But the blue line is a sloping line. I have tried bitwise and it's not helping. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have control over the code producing these images? If so, it may be possible to draw with a mode that leaves the *"blue"* and grey more separable.

Comment: Hi Mark, unfortunately, no. Though, the orange line is always a linearly downward sloping line, which to some extend can be sized accordingly. The challenging part is to fill in the gap -- I still do not have the direct solution...any idea would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, this one took some of my time. Here is what i did.

> Is there a way extract the gray portion and fill in the "blue" (now orange) portion where they intersect?

Yes, you can you use morphology to do that.

Importing necessary libraries.

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import rotate
```

Convert spaces, and find the grayscale threshold of the gray part.

```py
img = cv.imread('your_img')
img_rgb = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
thresh = cv.threshold(img_gray, 100, 255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = 255-thresh
```

Now you have the folowing image

[image: result]

What you need to do is fill the black space with some structuring element. Squares work on the bottom black space, while diamonds work on the top one. But the orange line has a slope that is not the same as the normal diamond (45 degree) so we need to rotate the diamond with that slope.

```py
def generate_diamond_se(N):
    if N % 2 == 0:
        raise ValueError("N must be an odd number to create a symmetric diamond.")

    diamond_se = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=np.uint8)

    mid = N // 2

    for i in range(mid + 1):
        for j in range(mid - i, mid + i + 1):
            diamond_se[i, j] = 1
            diamond_se[N - i - 1, j] = 1

    return diamond_se
```

```py
def rotate_diamond(diamond_se, angle_degrees):
    return rotate(diamond_se, angle_degrees, reshape=False)
```

How i used, 8 gave the best result.

```py
N = 41  # Size of the diamond
diamond_se = generate_diamond_se(N)
angle_degrees = 8  # Rotate by 8 degrees
rotated_diamond_se = rotate_diamond(diamond_se, angle_degrees)
closure = cv.morphologyEx(thresh,cv.MORPH_CLOSE,rotated_diamond_se)
```

The closure gives the following result:

[image: result]

Now we need to fill the bottom black space in the right way, which is done by using a square SE. Then use BITWISE to get the rgb picture back.

```py
kernel_square = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT,(15,15))
closure = cv.morphologyEx(closure,cv.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel_square,iterations=1)

intersection = cv2.bitwise_and(img_rgb, img_rgb, mask=closure)
```

Gives:

[image: result]

Now the little white part in the middle is removed by a creating a mask such as:

```py
lower_white = np.array([100, 100, 100], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_white = np.array([255, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)
white_mask = cv2.inRange(intersection, lower_white, upper_white)
intersection[white_mask > 0] = [0, 0, 0]
```

Which gives the final result:

[image: end]

The orange color can be removed by a similar mask of the above.

Comment: Thank you, Victor. This is really smart! Though, I don't quite get the diamond cv.morphologyEx() idea: do you mean creating a big diamond that is big enough to "overlap" the gray portion? What if the orange line is *always* a linearly downward sloping line? The slope (dy/dx) of the line can vary. Do you think this diamond method with larger size and rotation work (trial and error to get the angle right)?

Comment: The problem with morphology operators is that you need to specifically define one for your problem. Here, there are two intersections. The bottom intersection can be filled easily by a square or anything with a right angle. But the top intersection has a slope, and the morphology operator needs to have that slope as well. Then, what I understood from your problem is that you know the slope of the line. Then you can also infer some slope for the diamond. If you don't know the slope, you can find it by fitting a line through the image of the line that you attached.

Comment: Hi Victor, I've been playing with this in the last couple of days. I was able to extract the sloping line (hsv_mask). But, when I use that hsv_mask as kernel to "morph_close" the data, I'm getting a bunch of sloping white lines on closure. Am I missing something? I guess that I don't fully understand how alternating kernel in "morph_close" works.

`closure = cv.morphologyEx(data, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, hsv_mask)`

I also tried using a kernel of 2x4. It does fill the most of the gaps, but there are still some gaps remained open.

Comment: Your hsv mask is not a kernel. Kernels are structuring elements that pass through the image and do an operation for each pixel that they pass. The operation is either dilation or erosion. Closure is the Dilation followed by a Erosion.  The problem you are encoutering is the same as i did. Rectangular kernels are not enough for this problem because the slope of the orange line makes hard for them to do the things we want them to do. Thats why i used a diamond.